# Получение координат для GPS навигатора

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

Пишу приложение связанное с погодой, и мне нужно получить координаты , чтобы телефон автоматически настраивал локацию, и соответственно получал результаты по данной местности.

Запилил кое  как, с помощью кнопки. (при нажатии идет проверка координат).
Но нужно сделать без кнопок (чтобы приложение само проверяло текущие координаты, с каким-то интервалом по времени). 
А так же при входе, чтобы синхронизировало с данными (так же получать координаты во время входа).

Я пробовал запилить через асинтаск, но что-то я плохо возможно им владею (ничего не получилось).

Есть идеи? (Желательно кодом)

пс. - координаты я получаю с помощью LocationListener.

```
private void startGPS() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
    }

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lon = location.getLongitude();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
```

Comment: ммм, во-первых: `requestLocationUpdates` вызываться должен один раз с необходимом типом провайдера. Второй момент, который меня дико смущает - это пустой и бесполезный `if`. В-третьих `requestLocationUpdates` должен находится внутри Вашего пустого условия, дабы на android 6.0+ не вылетало. Ну и наконец, коль подписываетесь на такое дело, то также необходимо и отписываться, а то memory leak подхватите. Зачем тут асинктаск?. Запустите `startGPS` в `onResume` и не нужны будут кнопки. Но опять же необходимо отписываться, не забывайте про это.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Можете уточнить, пожалуйста, значение слова "отписываться".